# Can't submit to AppStore with beta version of Xcode

Tags: xcode

My Xcode version is 6.0 beta 4 and using iOS 8.0. I am trying to submit to the App Store and getting the following error message:

```
ERROR ITMS-9000: “This bundle is invalid. New apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with public (GM) versions of XCode 5.1.1 or higher and iOS 7 SDK. Do not submit apps built with beta software.”
```

Can someone please help me make sense of this error.

Answer (score 0):

Your "x-code version 6.0 **beta** 4" needs to be updated to a "**public (GM)** versions".

Answer (score 0):

If you read the error message, it tells you pretty directly that you can't use a beta version of Xcode to submit to the app store